# Application print function crashing in XP

Tags: wpf, printing

I made a WPF application for family business which was working fine earlier. Last month they formatted the PC and this time installed XP. While the application still works, but it crashes as soon as an invoice or any other print action is taken.

Following is the code. Let me know any workaround this problem or I need to install Windows 7 again.

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    PrintInvoice pi = new PrintInvoice();
    pi.DataContext = this.DataContext;
    PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        pi.Measure(new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth,
        printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight));
        pi.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight)));
        pi.Margin = new Thickness(40);
        pi.UpdateLayout();

        //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
        printDlg.PrintVisual(pi, "First Fit to Page WPF Print");
    }
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have been experiencing a similar problem when some of our customers downgraded to Windows XP. In our case the exception message from the system Event Log was

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
>
> Message: Unrecoverable system error

The solution was to install [Microsoft XML Paper Specification Essentials Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11816) on the target machines.